# Json Parsing Error : JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have created web service for mobile web site using mobile jquery and it will return json string.
When i start to parse this json using jQuery.parseJSON method, for sometimes it is working fine but in some situation ,it gives an error like:
`JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal` .

I already validate this json on jsonlint.com and it given a valid json message.

Follwoing is my json string.

`[{"ID":"468438","Text":"<a target='_blank' class='msg_links' href='http://bit.ly/jJa131' >http://bit.ly/jJa131</a> sdfdsfasd <br> <br> shankar (shankar) on Ogoing Small Business Social Network <br> <br> IT company ","CreatedText":"Jan 20 2012 6:01AM","UserID":"535","UserName":"shankar","FullName":"shankar","UpCategoryID":"8","UpCategoryName":"Deals","CategoryName":"Education & child care","IsRecommend":"False","RecommendUser":"","RecommendRating":"0","RecommendId":"0","LikedCount":"0","CommentsCount":"0","TotalRowCount":"1011","Attachment":"","RealFilename":"","Source":"","ImageURL":"http://ogoing.rigelnetworks.com/Images/Thumb/music_arts_icon_large_634666567215996287.jpg"},{"ID":"468437","Text":"<a target='_blank' class='msg_links' href='http://bit.ly/jJa131' >http://bit.ly/jJa131</a> asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf <br> shankar (shankar) on Ogoing Small Business Social Network <br> IT company ","CreatedText":"Jan 20 2012 5:35AM","UserID":"535","UserName":"shankar","FullName":"shankar","UpCategoryID":"8","UpCategoryName":"Deals","CategoryName":"Education & child care","IsRecommend":"False","RecommendUser":"","RecommendRating":"0","RecommendId":"0","LikedCount":"0","CommentsCount":"0","TotalRowCount":"1011","Attachment":"","RealFilename":"","Source":"","ImageURL":"http://ogoing.rigelnetworks.com/Images/Thumb/music_arts_icon_large_634666567215996287.jpg"},{"ID":"468434","Text":"asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfsadfasdfa ","CreatedText":"Jan 20 2012 4:55AM","UserID":"535","UserName":"shankar","FullName":"shankar","UpCategoryID":"8","UpCategoryName":"Deals","CategoryName":"Education & child care","IsRecommend":"False","RecommendUser":"","RecommendRating":"0","RecommendId":"0","LikedCount":"0","CommentsCount":"0","TotalRowCount":"1011","Attachment":"","RealFilename":"","Source":"","ImageURL":"http://ogoing.rigelnetworks.com/Images/Thumb/music_arts_icon_large_634666567215996287.jpg"},{"ID":"468433","Text":"asdfasdfasdf asdfasdf ","CreatedText":"Jan 20 2012 4:55AM","UserID":"535","UserName":"shankar","FullName":"shankar","UpCategoryID":"8","UpCategoryName":"Deals","CategoryName":"Education & child care","IsRecommend":"False","RecommendUser":"","RecommendRating":"0","RecommendId":"0","LikedCount":"0","CommentsCount":"0","TotalRowCount":"1011","Attachment":"","RealFilename":"","Source":"","ImageURL":"http://ogoing.rigelnetworks.com/Images/Thumb/music_arts_icon_large_634666567215996287.jpg"},{"ID":"468432","Text":"asdfasdfasdf ","CreatedText":"Jan 20 2012 4:54AM","UserID":"535","UserName":"shankar","FullName":"shankar","UpCategoryID":"8","UpCategoryName":"Deals","CategoryName":"Education & child care","IsRecommend":"False","RecommendUser":"","RecommendRating":"0","RecommendId":"0","LikedCount":"0","CommentsCount":"0","TotalRowCount":"1011","Attachment":"","RealFilename":"","Source":"","ImageURL":"http://ogoing.rigelnetworks.com/Images/Thumb/music_arts_icon_large_634666567215996287.jpg"},{"ID":"468012","Text":"Why this ? ","CreatedText":"Dec 20 2011 12:37AM","UserID":"537","UserName":"shankar","FullName":"shankar mahadevan","UpCategoryID":"1","UpCategoryName":"General","CategoryName":"Automotive","IsRecommend":"False","RecommendUser":"","RecommendRating":"0","RecommendId":"0","LikedCount":"1","CommentsCount":"0","TotalRowCount":"1011","Attachment":"","RealFilename":"","Source":"ogoing","ImageURL":"http://ogoing.rigelnetworks.com/Images/Thumb/img634661225851958174_org.png"},{"ID":"468011","Text":"Tixkhogclycyo ","CreatedText":"Dec 20 2011 12:37AM","UserID":"537","UserName":"shankar","FullName":"shankar mahadevan","UpCategoryID":"1","UpCategoryName":"General","CategoryName":"Automotive","IsRecommend":"False","RecommendUser":"","RecommendRating":"0","RecommendId":"0","LikedCount":"0","CommentsCount":"0","TotalRowCount":"1011","Attachment":"","RealFilename":"","Source":"ogoing","ImageURL":"http://ogoing.rigelnetworks.com/Images/Thumb/img634661225851958174_org.png"},{"ID":"468010","Text":"Zgkxxkxxhhl ","CreatedText":"Dec 20 2011 12:35AM","UserID":"537","UserName":"shankar","FullName":"shankar mahadevan","UpCategoryID":"1","UpCategoryName":"General","CategoryName":"Automotive","IsRecommend":"False","RecommendUser":"","RecommendRating":"0","RecommendId":"0","LikedCount":"0","CommentsCount":"0","TotalRowCount":"1011","Attachment":"","RealFilename":"","Source":"ogoing","ImageURL":"http://ogoing.rigelnetworks.com/Images/Thumb/img634661225851958174_org.png"},{"ID":"468009","Text":"Jfzkdlufil ","CreatedText":"Dec 20 2011 12:35AM","UserID":"537","UserName":"shankar","FullName":"shankar mahadevan","UpCategoryID":"1","UpCategoryName":"General","CategoryName":"Automotive","IsRecommend":"False","RecommendUser":"","RecommendRating":"0","RecommendId":"0","LikedCount":"0","CommentsCount":"0","TotalRowCount":"1011","Attachment":"","RealFilename":"","Source":"ogoing","ImageURL":"http://ogoing.rigelnetworks.com/Images/Thumb/img634661225851958174_org.png"},{"ID":"468007","Text":"hellooooooo ","CreatedText":"Dec 20 2011 12:21AM","UserID":"537","UserName":"shankar","FullName":"shankar mahadevan","UpCategoryID":"1","UpCategoryName":"General","CategoryName":"Automotive","IsRecommend":"False","RecommendUser":"","RecommendRating":"0","RecommendId":"0","LikedCount":"0","CommentsCount":"0","TotalRowCount":"1011","Attachment":"","RealFilename":"","Source":"ogoing","ImageURL":"http://ogoing.rigelnetworks.com/Images/Thumb/img634661225851958174_org.png"}]`

Please give me a solution for this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Format your JSON and accept answers on previous questions.

Comment: @EvilP I already validated this json in jsonlint.com and it gives valid json message.

Comment: @AtulPatel then there is nothing wrong with your json itself, considered some manipulation that is done, or that could change your json ?

Comment: you say you validate it, then post invalid json that doesn't validate... what solution do you expect??

Comment: your json string is valid. check with the code which will deal with manipulating the json results. is there any code you have written for retrieving the values of json string?

Comment: @mini I have written this code to parse this json in success function.  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d); In msg.d, I got this json string. In this function, i got this error.

Answer (score 12):

you can replace `\n` with `\\n`
for example

`yourJsonText = yourJsonText.Replace("\n","\\n");`

but if you use asp.net , it's better to encode your json string by

`yourJsonText = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(yourJsonText)`

Comment: 3 years later and this has helped me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's the
    `http://bit.ly/jJa131 sdfdsfasd 
    shankar (shankar)` part(s)

If you take that OUT (in both parts of the JSON) and pass it to [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/), the json validates succesfully.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually my json string for this parts in single line due to i have copied in clip board. So this is a not part of this issue. because i already validate this json on jsonlint.com.

Comment: if jsonlint says it's valid then it's probably valid - perhaps your calling code encodes/decodes it incorrectly?

Comment: I wrote **var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);** this line to parse this json string and it gives an error. msg.d returns this json string.

Answer (score 3):

Well I just had the same error and after some debugging, I noticed that, there was a newline in one of the strings which was throwing the above error. I actually had it at the end of the string just before the quote.

```
{"One":"My String \n"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, those error can caused by string literals like:

> \r\n

Be sure you properly encode this kind of literals if you use javascript's JSON.parse() function