# JSON parse error: bad escaped character

Tags: php, angularjs, json, parse-error

I'm getting this data from the database in the controller. I have used adslashes while saving and stropslashes while retrieving data. Please see controller and php file. I need to get this error fixed. I hope someone can tell what I'm doing wrong.

```
{"records":[{"id":"425","name":"a","content":"a\b<br>a<br>b"},{"id":"426","name":"1","content":"1\2"}]}
```

Also please check.. ionicnotepad.com/www this is what im practicing making. If you save data with a break in it.. anugular no matter what is showing 
 in the textarea. I tried everything. $sce, ng-bind-html, ng-sanitize, even the directive if you use divs and conteneditable.

```
//controller
app.value('count', 0);

app.controller('retrieveController', ['$sce','noteRetrieve','$state','alterNote','count','$ionicModal','$scope', function($sce, noteRetrieve, $state, alterNote, count, $ionicModal, $scope){
  var controller = this;
  var temp = localStorage.getItem("ascOrDsc");

  if(temp == "asc" || temp == null){
    controller.orderValue = 'id';
    controller.buttonDown = false;
    controller.buttonUp = true;
    localStorage.setItem("ascOrDsc", "asc");
  } else {
    controller.orderValue = '-id';
    controller.buttonUp = false;
    controller.buttonDown = true;
  }


  noteRetrieve.all()
    .success(function(data){

      var newData = data.replace(/&lt;br&gt;/g, '<br>');
      newData = newData.substring(1, newData.length - 1);
      // newData = angular.fromJson(newData);
      console.log(newData);

      // controller.allSaved = newData.records;
      // for(i = 0; i < newData.records.length; i++){
      //   count++;
      // }
      // controller.noOFNotes = count;
  });



  controller.deleteNote = function(noteId, noteName, noteContent){

    var currentNote = {
      id: noteId,
      name : noteName,
      content : noteContent
    };

    controller.itemId = noteId;

    alterNote.delete(currentNote)
      .success(function(){
          $state.go('notes.allnotes', {}, {reload: true});
      });
    };



    controller.changOrder = function(){
      var ascOrDscValue = localStorage.getItem("ascOrDsc");
      if(ascOrDscValue == 'asc'){
        controller.orderValue = '-id';
        controller.buttonUp = false;
        controller.buttonDown = true;
        localStorage.setItem("ascOrDsc", "desc");
      } else {
        controller.orderValue = 'id';
        controller.buttonUp = true;
        controller.buttonDown = false;
        localStorage.setItem("ascOrDsc", "asc");
      }
     };

     $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/createNote.html', {
       scope: $scope,
       animation: 'slide-in-up'

     }).then(function(modal){
       $scope.modal = modal;
     });

     $scope.createModal = function() {
       $scope.modal.show();
       localStorage.setItem('newNoteAvailable', 'no');
     };

     $scope.closeModal = function() {
       if(localStorage.getItem('newNoteAvailable') == 'yes'){
         $state.go('notes.allnotes', {}, {reload: true});
       } else {
         $state.go('notes.allnotes', {}, {reload: false});
       }
       $scope.modal.hide();
       $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/createNote.html', {
         scope: $scope,
         animation: 'slide-in-up'

       }).then(function(modal){
         $scope.modal = modal;
       });
     };

}]);



//php

$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM noteFile";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {
      $outp .= ",";
    }
    $outp .= '{"id":"'  . $rs["id"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"name":"'   . $rs["name"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"content":"'. $rs["data"] . '"}';
}

$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';


$outp = json_encode($outp);

// var_dump($outp);

$outp = stripslashes($outp);


echo ($outp);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal, in this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487058/how-to-solve-json-parse-bad-control-character-in-string-literal-in-this-code)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487058/how-to-solve-json-parse-bad-control-character-in-string-literal-in-this-code  OR  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684925/json-parsing-error-json-parse-bad-control-character-in-string-literal  OR  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573525/bad-control-character-error-in-json-parse

Comment: I read that and i have 2 question there. But the first one is about the escaped character. I dont understand i have to get a backslash in the end in json and when that happens it gives an error. However if you see closely. the is a sting beore that that i am which also has backslash and that is not giving an error...

Answer (score 2):

The part `"content":"1\2"` is not valid, it should be `"content":"1\\2"`

Comment: im trying and trying nbut im not able to make it work.. can anybody tell me exactly what to do?

Comment: Don't use adslashes or any other function before you save the JSON to the database. Also do not use stropslashes while retirving data. Just save the json as sting and it should be fine. JSON encode handle the escaping: `echo json_encode(['content' => '1\2']); //{"content":"1\\2"}`

Comment: {"id":"462","name":"test","content":"a"}]} .. i entered a\b and \b have escaped

Comment: Error: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 406 of the JSON data . this is the error i get with this approach

Comment: while saving before post call in angular im doing toJson when i reach php file for saving im doing json decode.. and json_encode before sending data back from server and when i get data back in controller im doing fromJson.. I hope this all is in order...